# Scaling websites width without losing vertical focus point of content

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, scale

I've got a basic website with very long mostly-text content:

HTML goes simplified like this:

```
<body>
<div class="content" id="01">
    <p>LONG TEXT</p>
</div>

<div class="content" id="02">
    <p>LONG TEXT</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Same goes on with about 40 more id's.

CSS looks for these parts like this:

```
.content {
    max-width: 600px;
    min-width: 240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

So the content divs are scaled down with browser window / viewport. This finally takes us to my **problem:**

Whenever I scale the width of my browser window down, the width of the content div also scales down and so the content itself gets longer, or taller should i say. This leads to situation where current point of focus in content moves down. Especially bad this is when switching mobile device from landscape to portrait orientation or vice versa.

I'm now trying to find solution that scales the height of content both up and down, keeping the current vertical focus point on the screen. Does anyone have any ideas how this could be done in HTML, CSS or JS? Content divs have unique ids, single div not being very long so I guess that at least with JS this should be possible by somehow tracking the currently displayed id?

I hope I got some sense to this, while english not being my native language.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should do is set the `<p>` width fixed to the min-width of `div.content`, so it will never change it's width, but the parent `<div>` will, according to the current orientation.

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/dyjXC/1/

CSS:

```
body{ width: 300px; } /* portrait or landscape */
div.content
{ 
    max-width: 600px; 
    min-width: 240px; 
    background: salmon; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
div.content > p
{
    text-align: center; /* I centered both the text and... */
    margin: 0px auto;   /* ... the p itself, but you can use default to left */
    width: 240px; 
    background: lightgray;
}
```

I hope it works as expected.